# How can I handle the multiple click action to single button for API calling and get the true response from API

Tags: ios, swift

I just want to know the method to handle multiple click event on single button. (e.g. FACEBOOK like button if I tapped multiple time then it may work perfectly.)

Below code give you some idea and if there is any appropriate solution then give me as soon as possible.

```
class LikeViewController: UIViewController {

    //MARK:- Outlets
    @IBOutlet weak var btnLike: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblDescription: UILabel!
    
    //MARK:- Variables
    var objModelWatchList:WatchListModel?
    var objUser = WatchListModel()
    
    //MARK:- Lifecycle methods
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        getWatchList()
        
    }

    //MARK:- Functions
    
    //Function for prepare UI
    func prepareUI() {
        btnLike.isSelected = isLike()
    }
    
    //Function for prepare data from api
    func getWatchList() {
        objUser.videoId = 216
        objUser.type = "VIDEO"
        APIService.sharedInstance.getWatchList(parameters: objUser.toDictionary() as [String : AnyObject], success: { (dataSuccess) -> (Void) in
            self.objModelWatchList = dataSuccess
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.prepareUI()
                self.lblDescription.text = self.objModelWatchList?.message
            }
        }) { (resultFailure) -> (Void) in
            print(resultFailure)
        }
    }
    
    
    //Function to varify the status of like
    func isLike() -> Bool {
        return objModelWatchList!.status == 1 ? true : false
    }
    
    //MARK:- Actions
    @IBAction func btnLikeClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
                sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected
                self.getWatchList()
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, could you please share what you have done so far and what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show your latest non-working attempt at solving this problem. It is usually more instructive to see fixes to your code than to read someone else's solution. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You have to disable your button when API call and when u will get right response after the processing on that response you have to enable it.

Its works for me. I have a same issue.

Comment: Just i want to make my button as FACEBOOK like button so your solution doesn't work me any way thanks for response.

Answer (score 0):

if you refer to manage several events taps...I  recommend that use tapGestureRecognizer or variants, these can manage events that you comment for example...:

- Single tap,double tap or more taps to trigger function event
- Hold tap [UILongPressGestureRecognizer]

if you refer to same button called severals function in diferents situations i recommend the use un tag button for example:

```
function examplefunctionA(){
  //Another Proccess
  //Another Proccess
  self.button.tag = 2
}

function examplefunctionB(){
  //Another Proccess
  //Another Proccess
  self.button.tag = 1
}

func buttonclicked(sender: UIButton) {
    if sender.tag == 1 {
       examplefunctionA()
    }else if sender.tag == 2 {
       examplefunctionB()
    }
}
```

Comment: as par mentioned above i want to take only single button but make it as FACEBOOK like button.

Comment: @AhemadabbasVagh , sorry but you modified the question in the last hour

Comment: Sorry my apologies but before the modification i already mentioned about single button.

Answer (score 0):

The way to achieve this is to use a debouncer. Make the delay to be like 1 second, so if the user is tapping on the button multiple times before 1 second, it will cancel the previous action. So, you only need to locally update the button like/dislike state, and only call the API when the user stopped tapping.